# F# sorting issue

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Whats wrong with this code? Why wont it sort?

```
let rec sort = function
  | []         -> []
  | [x]        -> [x]
  | x1::x2::xs -> if x1 <= x2 then x1 :: sort (x2::xs)
                              else x2 :: sort (x1::xs)
```

Suppost to take 
 sort [3;1;4;1;5;9;2;6;5];;

and return:
val it : int list = [1; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 5; 6; 9]

Answer (score 2):

Your code is like one bubble cycle in [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It will take max element to the last position and some other bigger elements to the right.

Note that you are only traversing original list only once. It has linear complexity and we all know that sorting using only comparison has to be O(n*log n).

You can repeat that cycle more times if you want to sort this list.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

think about what can end up in the first position ... right now it can only be the first or the second position in your list (the `if` inside the last case)

Comment: It's suppose to be a base case tho. When the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
let rec ssort = function
    [] -> []
    | x::xs -> 
        let min, rest =
            List.fold_left (fun (min,acc) x ->
                             if h<min then (h, min::acc)
                             else (min, h::acc))
              (x, []) xs
        in min::ssort rest
```